# A sudden change in my saved PDF documents from the file format I originally saved them

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, icons, adobe-acrobat

Every PDF document I save is in Adobe Acrobat because that is the program I use. The Adobe icon was always shown before the file name. I opened my files today and every Adobe icon was changed to an icon that looks like a mini Chrome (I think HTML, but I’m not sure).

**New icons below:**

[image: New Icons]

---

I know that I can go into my control panel and change the default settings back to Adobe. I did that.

**Corrected icons below:**

[image: Corrected Icons]

---

I’m wondering how they changed in the first place. If HTML (or whatever type of file that was) is connected to Google Chrome in any way, I did just have to uninstall and reinstall my Chrome browser because it was nonresponsive (if that helps).

Comment: Also to find out what file it is you can enable file extensions, Read this:http://www.thewindowsclub.com/show-file-extensions-in-windows

Comment: I just want to point out, for completeness and clarity, that the associated program and the icon being displayed has *nothing to do with the file format*. Your description does not cause me to suspect that the files themselves have been altered or changed to a different format. Though I will add that this is a misapprehension that is mostly fostered by the UI and by hiding file extensions

Answer (score 2):

How did they change? That really can't be answered as there are tons of ways it could have been changed, but here is a rundown of what probably caused it. (but not all)

1. "Freeware" Freeware is free software that you download, these tend to offer that you change your home page, install software, etc to earn money. Consider running some kind of Adware remover.
2. "Malware/Virus" It's possible some virus or malware got installed onto your computer and changed all of your shortcuts and messed with your files. Check your shortcuts to chrome and other common applications to check that the point to the correct location, also consider running an antivirus/malware.
3. "Adware" Adware can often be installed with an installer or even by visiting a website although if you did have some you would probably experience popups on your browser. Install an Adware Remover.
4. "Trojan Virus" A trojan virus installs itself into a computer by misleading a user.
   All in all, it probably got changed by some program you installed.

Some adware removers are:

1. [Malwarebytes Adwcleaner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY7oClxLjSAhVj_IMKHZ6SCZEQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.malwarebytes.com%2Fadwcleaner%2F&usg=AFQjCNEpej7SO08PPznIwMoH7zgmNvFXSQ&sig2=sUKhna8_2UnteUEDLBZwhw&bvm=bv.148747831,d.amc)
2. [Anything else from here](https://www.techsupportall.com/top-best-free-adware-removal-tools/)

Most of these also include an anti-malware/virus tool as well, but I won't recommend them and I'll leave what to use up to you

Answer (score 0):

It could have possibly been caused by the Chrome reinstall.  (You're right -- that is the Chrome icon.)  Windows itself can change default file associations as well, as can certain programs.  For example, I've seen image file types have their associations changed more often in Windows 10 than in older versions of Windows.